how to build a widget completely before rendering in flutter?
I have a slider widget inside my home page that goes through a complicated process to be built and it takes about 4 seconds to build.
I wanted this widget to be completely created on the splash which takes 3 seconds, before the user enters the home page, and then send the ready slider widget to the home page with flutter navigation.
But apparently, in Flutter, a widget is not built before it is placed in the build method and returned (rendered).
Please note that the problem is not related to calling API.
And I don't want to use the Stack widget as a trick because it's supposed to navigate from splash to home and that i use Bloc for state management.

4 seconds? what exactly takes so long?

Making slider with flutter_gallery_3d.
